# iMacros - Removing HTML Elements

Tags: imacros

I don't know much about HTML or imacros.
I'm trying to make an imacros script that takes a screenshot of an image on the page, but the website has a navigation bar which when imacros takes the screenshot covers half of the image.

How can I create an imacros script to remove this navigation bar from my screen?

In inspect elements, I can get rid of it by removing:

So how can I remove this in imacros please?

Thank you

Comment: hello, please help me :)

Comment: Try to use the parameter `CONTENT=SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT` in the [`TAG` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG) of the positioned image.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript for this.
To remove element by ID use this code.

```
var id = window.document.getElementById("page-container");
id.parentNode.removeChild(id);
```

Instead of `"page-container"` put your ID you want to remove

To remove elements by `class`
Use this:

```
var collection = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("Class-name");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, function(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with imacros and url goto as iim script. Or you can use pure javascript as js file in your imacros.

Example with url goto and class name:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:var<SP>delclass=window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("class<SP>name");Array.prototype.forEach.call(delclass,function(node){node.parentNode.removeChild(node)});
```